# WWW fileupload using VB.NET or Access/VBA

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, file-upload, ftp, vba

I would like to ask if there's a possibility to upload files to a webserver or an ftpserver using VB.NET or Access/VBA.

I think if there are possibilities - VB.NET is more powerful than Access/VBA, is that right?

Are there any chances using webservices?

And FTP? I think there must be a chance to copy files using VB.NET or Access via FTP ...

Is there anyone who could help me?

Thomas

Comment: If you have the option of using VB.NET then that will probably be the easiest way (see the answer from @DouglasBarbin, below). There are ways of doing FTP transfers via VBA code but they are not as straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would do it using FTP:

```
Dim ftpRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.myserver.com/foo.txt"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
ftpRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
ftpRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

Dim myFile() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\somefile.txt")

Using ftpStream As System.IO.Stream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream()
   ftpStream.Write(myFile, 0, myFile.Length)
   ftpStream.Close()
End Using
```